# Android bitmap list to image array

Tags: listview, blob, android-bitmap

I have a bitmap list and I want to use it in a listView . I'm trying to convert this to image array and use it in listview . What should I do??
Is there any other ways to do this?
This list contains some blobs from database?

Answer (score 0):

I found this from another post on here. Takes blob and converts it back to an image. With a list view you can then attach an image file and send this as your source.

```
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("Pic");

            int blobLength = (int) blob.length();

            byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
            final BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(blobAsBytes));

            label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bufferedImage))
```

However I would suggest looking at libraries such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) these will be much more helpful and easier to use and maintain in the long run.